# Convert char array to CString in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, c-strings, strcat

I am unable to convert the char * to CString.. the last 2 print lines print nothing...I need it as part of cstring to be able to pass it to a function..

```
char result[500];
strcpy(result, "\\\\.\\pipe\\");                    
strcat(result, a["BLOB"][i].GetString());// just appending to "result" a string I am reading from json file..
CString  temp(result);
printf("\n1-The pipeName we are looking at is %s \n", result);
printf("\n2-The pipeName we are looking at is %s \n", temp);
printf("\n3-The pipeName we are looking at is %s \n", CString(result,500));
```

Comment: What is `CString` and where does it come from? It's not part of standard C++.

Comment: Between `CString` and `.GetString()`, I am *assuming* this is referring to WinAPI, and have added the tag... a complete example (with includes) would have clarified that.

Comment: @DevSolar It is probably [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=vs-2019), which is in [tag:MFC], rather than [tag:winapi].

Comment: @TanveerBadar: OK... I come from the Amiga and went from there directly to Linux, so everything from Microsoft is "WinAPI" to me. :-D Feel free to re-tag.

Comment: Yes @DevSolar it is the link you provided.

Comment: FYI, the `CString` type is either C# or C++/CLI (a.k.a. managed C++).  The *standard* C++ language does not have a `CString` type.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It's the MFC's (Thanks, Tanveer) C++ string type, and has been well before the monstrosity that is C++/CLI ever saw the light of day.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is crude. Using `%s` with `printf` will assume that the first pointer-size amount of bytes in whatever you pass to it are actually a pointer to a string (aka `char*`).

That may or may not be true for `CString`. In your case it seems that it isn't.

To use printf you need to do it more like:

```
printf("\n2-The pipeName we are looking at is %s \n", temp.GetString());
```

Or else just stop using `printf` and use something with more type-safety, such as `cout`

Answer (score 2):

Build the string directly into the `CString`, and use the builtin cast to `const char *` when printing.

```
CString  temp("\\\\.\\pipe\\");
temp += a["BLOB"][i].GetString(); // or: temp.Format("\\\\.\\pipe\\%s", a["BLOB"][i].GetString());
printf("-The pipeName we are looking at is %s\n", (const char *)temp);
```

Comment: The format arguments we are passing are incorrect.. any suggestions?

Comment: @ccoding What's the exact line of code the error points to? Also, you don't say what type `a["BLOB"][i].GetString()` returns, but if it's *not* a `const char *` then you probably need to add a cast to that.

Answer (score 1):

How would `printf()` know what `CString` is? What a class is? How to convert `CString` to a c-style string?

This is working as expected.

What you are looking for is probably documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/cstring-operations-relating-to-c-style-strings?view=vs-2019#_core_using_cstring_as_a_c.2d.style_null.2d.terminated_string), based on the assumption that MFC/WFC also provide a `CString`.